# Highcharts shared tooltip between charts with multiple series and shared tooltip

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to set shared tooltip between charts. It works nice only if tooltip doesn't have `shared: true`, if I set `shared: true` I get error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'a[0].category') highcharts.js:3259
```

I prepared example: http://jsfiddle.net/CAKQH/24408/

If you move cursor on first chart - it works nice, also if you comment `shared: true` it works, but if you move cursor on second chart you'll get an error.

Did someone faced this error? 
Help me to solve it, please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem occurs because you have `shared: true` on one chart, while having it default (false) on the other. This is a problem because the `tooltip.refresh` method will take different paths and use the input differently based the chart having shared set to true or false.

You can find this branching [in the source code](http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js) on line 8806, for the `tooltip.refresh` method:

```
// shared tooltip, array is sent over
if (shared && !(point.series && point.series.noSharedTooltip)) {
    ....
}
// single point tooltip
else {
    ....
}
```

You can handle this by doing a branching inside your `syncTooltip` method to handle the different cases like this ([example JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CAKQH/24410/)):

```
function syncTooltip(container, p) {
    var i = 0;
    for (; i < charts.length; i++) {
        if (container.id != charts[i].container.id) {
            if(charts[i].tooltip.shared) {
                charts[i].tooltip.refresh([charts[i].series[0].data[p]]);
            }
            else {
                charts[i].tooltip.refresh(charts[i].series[0].data[p]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This way you can freely set shared to true or false on both charts.

Unfortunately your `plotOptions.series.point.events.mouseOver`-event doesn't capture points that are "selected" through the `shared: true` functionality, so you will have to find an alternate event to properly capture this situation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the short answer is I should use array in function refresh parameter.

Comment: Yep, thank you! Very appreciate you! I wrote it for somebody who will face same problem.