# Highcharts - multiple yAxis each with its own tooltip

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is this possible?

[image: crosshairs multiple yAxis lines multiple tooltips]

I already played with `tooltip.shared` and `tooltip.crosshairs` but I couldn't manage to get something similar.

EDIT: Something like [Wunderground's weather forecast graph](http://www.wunderground.com/weather-forecast/zmw:10001.5.99999) would be perfect (try to "mouseover" the graph)

Comment: I did some tries on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z7d88d8v/ but nothing similar to what I'm looking for

Comment: Looks like this was done in related SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24635610/highcharts-shared-tooltip-between-charts-with-multiple-series-and-shared-tooltip

Comment: In short: there is one tooltip per chart. If you really need this, I suggest to wrap `tooltip.refresh` method, and create there separate tooltips (including positioning logic, formatted texts etc.).

Comment: @PawełFus thanks, i'll give it a try. Is there any provided properties that I could reuse to easily get the positioning logic?

Comment: Find in the source code line: `getPosition: function (boxWidth, boxHeight, point) { ... } `- that will help you with positioning separate tooltips for points (like this: `var position = chart.tooltip.getPosition(width, height, point);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [tooltip.positioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.positioner) in synchronous highcharts can results to required behaviour.

```
tooltip: {
      positioner: function(labelWidth, labelHeight, point) {
        var tooltipX, tooltipY;
        tooltipX = point.plotX + this.chart.plotLeft + 20;
        tooltipY = point.plotY + this.chart.plotTop - 20;
        return {
          x: tooltipX,
          y: tooltipY
        };
      }
    }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/3297j5ma/) demo modifying [synchronized-charts](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/synchronized-charts) demo

**Update** Fix for tooltip hiding at extreme right

```
tooltip: {
      positioner: function(labelWidth, labelHeight, point) {
        var tooltipX, tooltipY;
        if (point.plotX > 340) {
          tooltipX = point.plotX + this.chart.plotLeft - 150;
        } else {
          tooltipX = point.plotX + this.chart.plotLeft + 20;
        }
        tooltipY = point.plotY + this.chart.plotTop - 20;
        console.log(tooltipX);
        return {
          x: tooltipX,
          y: tooltipY
        };
      }
    }
```

[Fixed Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/3297j5ma/1/)