# Multiple pie charts in 1 graph with split tooltip Highcharts.js

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, tooltip, pie-chart

Currently I'm trying to create a single Highchart graph with 3 pie charts. (All charts contain exactly the same amount of datapoints). When I hover over a piece of the pie I want 3 tooltips appear on all 3 pie charts at the same given point.

I tried using

```
{
    tooltip: { split: true} 
}
```

but throws a JavaScript error and doesn't seem to work on pie charts. I can't seem to be able to get this to work properly. I also tried redefining `Highcharts.Tooltip.prototype.renderSplit` but couldn't get it to work either.

I have the following: 
https://jsfiddle.net/Visualq/4o1uyazr/13/

Comment: This answer tells you how tooltips for multiple charts can be synced: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31166038/highcharts-multiple-yaxis-each-with-its-own-tooltip taken from this resource on highcharts' pages: https://www.highcharts.com/blog/snippets/synchronisation-of-multiple-charts/

Comment: @ewolden Thank you for your comment, however pie charts can't be synced the way it's described in the question as `searchPoint` does not work on pie charts (I can't find the source of this claim but I tried this). Split should do exactly what I want but for some reason it breaks the tooltip.

Comment: My bad, I did some investigation, and found where it fails, seems like a bug, where split tooltip expects a series with x and y values. Whereas a pie does not really fall into this category. Here I put a breakpoint on the error: https://i.imgur.com/4xXzG6K.png It fails on setting `anchorX` because `f` is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create multiple tooltips on chart load event and manage them on point mouse over event.

1. Create for each series one tooltip

   ```
   Highcharts.chart('container', {
     chart: {
       type: 'pie',
       events: {
         load() {
           this.tooltips = this.series.slice(1).map(
           series => new Highcharts.Tooltip(
             this,
             Highcharts.merge(this.options.tooltip)
           )
         )
       }
     }
   },
   ```
2. On mouse over call `tooltip.refresh(point)` where point is the point which should be hovered. I call for the points with the same names.

   ```
   plotOptions: {
     series: {
       point: {
         events: {
           mouseOver(e) {
             const otherSeries = this.series.chart.series.filter(
               series => series !== this.series
             )

             const otherPoints = otherSeries.map(
               series => series.points.find(
                 point => point.name === this.name
               )
             )

             this.series.chart.tooltips.forEach((tooltip, i) => {
               tooltip.refresh(otherPoints[i])
             })
           }
         }
       }
     }
   },
   ```
3. Wrap tooltip's hide method so all tooltips will be hidden simultaneously.

   ```
   Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.Tooltip.prototype, 'hide', function(p, delay) {
     if (this === this.chart.tooltip) {
       p.call(this, delay)

       this.chart.tooltips.forEach(tooltip => {
         p.call(tooltip, delay)
       })
     }
   })
   ```

live example: https://jsfiddle.net/8w30m3o8/

If you do not want tooltips to swap between series, you should assign a tooltip to a specific series, e.g. the main tooltip should be refreshed only with the points from the first series, the second tooltip with the points from the second series, and so on.

---

Possibly easier solution would be to use 3 charts and synchronise tooltips similarly as it is done in this example: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/synchronized-charts

Comment: This answer was fantastic for my situation! Thanks for this answer.

I did want to add, though, that this method does not handle the hover state. If you wish to add that as well, you can do `otherPoints[i].setState('hover');` in the loop where you perform tooltip.refresh