# Synchronized tooltips positioning with line and horizontal bar charts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I'm having trouble aligning tooltip position on bar chart. Tooltip positioning works fine if all charts are line chart but not with bar/column charts. Could the Highcharts experts please help me with this issue?

http://jsfiddle.net/yhenwtsb/1/

```
var charts = [],
  options1, options2;

function syncTooltip(container, p) {
  var i = 0;
  for (; i < charts.length; i++) {
    if (container.id != charts[i].container.id) {
      if (charts[i].tooltip.shared) {
        charts[i].tooltip.refresh([charts[i].series[0].data[p]]);
      } else {
        charts[i].tooltip.refresh(charts[i].series[0].data[p]);
      }
    }
  }
}

options1 = {
  chart: {
    type: "column",
    inverted: true
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      point: {
        events: {
          mouseOver: function() {
            syncTooltip(this.series.chart.container, this.x - 1);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
  }
};

options2 = {
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      point: {
        events: {
          mouseOver: function() {
            syncTooltip(this.series.chart.container, this.x - 1);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
  }
};



charts[0] = new Highcharts.Chart($.extend(true, {}, options1, {
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container1',
    marginLeft: 40, // Keep all charts left aligned
  },
  tooltip: {
    shared: true,
    crosshairs: true,
    valueDecimals: 2
  },
  series: [{
    data: [
      [1, 29.9],
      [2, 71.5],
      [3, 106.4]
    ]
  }, {
    data: [
      [1, 59.9],
      [2, 91.5],
      [3, 136.4]
    ]
  }]
}));


charts[1] = new Highcharts.Chart($.extend(true, {}, options2, {
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container2',
    marginLeft: 40, // Keep all charts left aligned
  },
  tooltip: {
    shared: false
  },
  series: [{
    data: [
      [1, 29.9],
      [2, 71.5],
      [3, 106.4]
    ]
  }]
}));
```

Comment: Hi @Sudhakar, Could you exaplain your problem more precisely? In my opinion the tooltip works correctly. What result would you like to achieve?

Comment: Yes, the tooltips work as expected. I want the tooltips in both charts to align on the vertical axis as described in this SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31166038/highcharts-multiple-yaxis-each-with-its-own-tooltip

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still do not quite understand what the result would look like. A tooltip is assigned to a point or points, not to an axis. If you remove `inverted` option, the tooltip works better: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ay2tusxe/

Comment: My use case requires horizontal bar charts and i want the tooltip (on bar chart) to show up along mouse cursor's y-axis position, so that both tooltips align vertically on top of each other

Comment: something like this https://ibb.co/qYVdFTq

Comment: Hi @Sudhakar, Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2w9683gb/ and let me know if something like that you would like to achieve?

Comment: Awesome! yes, thats exactly what I was looking for. Thank you @ppotaczek

Comment: Hi @Sudhakar, I am glad I could help. You can vote and accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `tooltip.followPointer` to `true` and add a small plugin to synchronize the second chart:

```
(function(H) {
    H.wrap(H.Pointer.prototype, 'runPointActions', function(proceed, e, p) {
        proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

        var tooltipPos = this.chart.tooltip.now;

        Highcharts.charts.forEach(function(chart) {
            if (chart !== this.chart) {
                chart.tooltip.updatePosition({
                    plotX: tooltipPos.x - chart.plotLeft,
                    plotY: tooltipPos.y - chart.plotTop
                });
            }
        }, this);
    });
}(Highcharts));
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2w9683gb/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.followPointer

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts