# Show tooltips on multiple charts - HighCharts

Tags: highcharts

When I mouse over on one chart, tooltip will be displayed. Same time, I want tooltip to be displayed on the other chart also in the same position.

I have added code to listen for mouseOver event and then, display the tooltip on other chart. However, I am not able to get the position in mouseOver event.

In the jsfiddle example, I have created, I am hard-coding the position as always 1. But, instead it should be dynamic and should be the same position as where the tooltip is displayed now.

```js
$(function() {

  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'container'
    },

    series: [{
      data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
  });

  var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'container1'
    },

    series: [{
      data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }],
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        events: {
          mouseOver: function() {
            //instead of data[i] it should be data[xposition]
            chart.series[0].data[1].setState('hover');
            chart.tooltip.refresh(chart.series[0].data[1]);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container1" style="height: 400px; width: 500px"></div>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; width: 500px"></div>
<button id="button">Select point</button>
```

How to get the position in mouseOver event?

Thanks for the help.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mp7ctwkL/5/)

EDIT:

There is a similar question [Highcharts shared tooltip between charts with multiple series and shared tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24635610/highcharts-shared-tooltip-between-charts-with-multiple-series-and-shared-tooltip). However, that question is mostly revolving around the shared property. In this case, I am not adding shared property in any of the charts.

Comment: Have a look at the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31166038/highcharts-multiple-yaxis-each-with-its-own-tooltip . There you can see a working example of synced axes and tooltips.

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried to use the same.

http://jsfiddle.net/mp7ctwkL/6/

However, I need a mouseMove rather than mouseOver I guess. But, mouseMove is not working.

Comment: I made a minor adjustment to your code, added your `event` to `point` instead of the entire `series`, and it seems to work now: http://jsfiddle.net/mp7ctwkL/7/ .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Highcharts shared tooltip between charts with multiple series and shared tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24635610/highcharts-shared-tooltip-between-charts-with-multiple-series-and-shared-tooltip)

Comment: @ewolden: Works perfectly. Thank you so much